# Error sequence contains no elements when using context.database.sqlquery

Tags: c#

```
 return Task.Run<MAUser>(() => 
 { 
   return context.Database
    .SqlQuery<MAUser>("exec dbo.UserRecordGet @Name, @Email, @Id", parameters)
    .FirstOrDefault();
 });
```

why does this return "Sequence contains  no elements" error and not null?

Comment: Using the debugger, what is the result of `context.Database    .SqlQuery<MAUser>("exec dbo.UserRecordGet @Name, @Email, @Id", parameters)` ?

Comment: the same error message "Sequence contains no elements"